# SQL Grouping entries with a different value

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's assume I have a report that displays an ID and VALUE from different tables

```
  | ID | VALUE |
  |----|-------|
1 | 1  | 1     |
2 | 1  | 0     |
3 | 1  | 1     |
4 | 2  | 0     |
5 | 2  | 0     |
```

My goal is to display this table with grouped IDs and VALUEs. My rule to grouping VALUEs would be "If VALUE contains atleast one '1' then display '1' otherwise display '0'".

My current SQL is (simplified)

```
SELECT
    TABLE_A.ID,
    CASE
        WHEN TABLE_B.VALUE = 1 OR TABLE_C.VALUE NOT IN (0,1,2,3)
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS VALUE
FROM TABLE_A, TABLE_B, TABLE_C
GROUP BY
    TABLE_A.ID
    (CASE
        WHEN TABLE_B.VALUE = 1 OR TABLE_C.VALUE NOT IN (0,1,2,3)
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END)
```

The output is following

```
  | ID | VALUE |
  |----|-------|
1 | 1  | 1     |
2 | 1  | 0     |
3 | 2  | 0     |
```

Which is half way to the output I want

```
  | ID | VALUE |
  |----|-------|
1 | 1  | 1     |
2 | 2  | 0     |
```

So my Question is: How do I extend my current SQL (or change it completely) to get my desired output?

Comment: Why not just select `MAX()`?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: what about TABLE, FOREIGN_TABLE Structres

Comment: @GummiBoat Here you don't provide TABLE, FOREIGN_TABLE structure, here only maybe TABLE structure is present

Comment: My bad, I thought standard SQL would suffice. I added the Oracle Tag. I'm working in Oracle SQL Developer.

The table structures are a bit complex and I don't see why they would matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `value` is always 0 or 1, you can do:

```
select id, max(value) as value
from t
group by id;
```

If `value` can take on other values:

```
select id,
       max(case when value = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as value
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: I'm actually an idiot, I forgot to take the CASE WHEN out of my GROUP BY. Now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having only 0 and 1 as distinct values in FOREIGN_VALUE column then using max() function as mentioned by HoneyBadger in the comment will fulfill your requirement.

```
SELECT
   ID,
   MAX(FOREIGN_VALUE) AS VALUE
FROM (SELECT
         ID,
        CASE WHEN FOREIGN_VALUE = 1
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END AS FOREIGN_VALUE
      FROM TABLE, 
      FOREIGN_TABLE)
GROUP BY
ID;
```

Comment: Sadly I am setting the 1 and 0 myself, FOREIGN_VALUE = 1 is not the only condition in the final SQL, that's why I went through the trouble of using a CASE WHEN.

Comment: I don't think MAX is the right way, since - as I already said - there are multiple conditions to set the VALUE row and I cannot directly refer to one column with MAX, unless there is a way to MAX my freshly made VALUE column.

Comment: Please mention few of the other conditions to get the clear picture of your requirement.Thanks for the edit Radim.

Comment: @GummiBoat I think you should be more explicit in the question to get responses being more accurate to your needs

Comment: I edited the SQL of my question and don't think I can provide more information than that. If I try to implement the SQL as above, I don't get any results since the server keeps querying.